# Why java swing drawLine doesn't correct width?

Tags: java, swing, line, draw, graphic

I am writing some simple java graphic app. This is my problem:

```
package graphic;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel panel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        setTitle("Test Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        panel = new JPanel(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                final int MAX = 100;

                //Draw grid
                for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
                    if (i % 2 == 0){
                        g.drawLine(0, i, MAX, i);
                        g.drawLine(i, 0, i, MAX);
                    }

                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 0);//width = 1
                g.drawLine(0, 2, 1, 2);//width = 2
                g.drawLine(0, 4, 2, 4);//width = 3
                g.drawLine(0, 6, 3, 6);//width = 4


            }
        };

        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(panel);

    }

}
```

I draw 4 lines in the JPanel. The result is as follows:
[image]
But the second line take 3 "square pixel", while x1 = 0, x2 = 1 then line width is 2 square only?
There is the same problem with the 3rd and 4th line.
Any one can explain for me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

1. Something is messed up with your graphics system. Perhaps you have some kind of magnification or scaling on your screen going on.
2. There's a bug in your runtime implementation. If so you may want to file a bug and specify your os and runtime.

This is the result on my system:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, my os is Windows 8.1 64 bit.
 Java version: javac 1.8.0_05
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: That's strange. I'd file a bug report if I were you.

Comment: (really:-) - true is that is required to override getPreferredSize for JPanel, then all coordinated are from getHeight/Weight

Comment: @aioobe I'm think that there is bug about issue with DoubleBuffering, have to check (not presents in all Java8_xxx versions)

Comment: I'm sure there is an issue with NVidia GPU drivers on Win8/8.1_64b with Java8 (a few times here)

Answer (score 0):

It displays correctly on my (Windows) system. However, I'd suggest adding the following lines in the paintComponent method:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

(Setting stroke control to pure can clean up some kinds of sloppy rasterization.)